# Apache Pinot server component consumes unexpected amount of memory

Tags: apache-pinot, pinot

#### Problem Description:

Docker is used to deploy Apache Pinot on production servers (VMs).

[Pinot's official documentation](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/) has been followed for this purpose.

#### What has been done

Pinot servers consume more memory than the *data* and *replication factor* we have.

The things has been tried were the followings:

- Defining `Xms` and `Xmx` flags for JVM in ‍JAVA_OPTS environment variables
- Setup monitoring on machines in order to gain the observability
- Remove the indices (like inverted index) from the table definition

[image: Table size]

[image: Node exporter screenshot]

**System Specification:**
we have 3 servers, 2 controllers and 2 brokers with the following specifications:

- 24 core CPU
- 64 gigabytes of Memory
- 738 gigabytes of SSD disk

**Sample Docker-compose file on one of the servers:**

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  pinot-server:
    image: apachepinot/pinot:0.11.0
    command: "StartServer -clusterName bigdata-pinot-ansible -zkAddress 172.16.24.14:2181,172.16.24.15:2181 -configFileName /server.conf"
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: server1
    container_name: server1
    ports:
      - "8096-8099:8096-8099"
      - "9000:9000"
      - "8008:8008"
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Dplugins.dir=/opt/pinot/plugins -Xms4G -Xmx20G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xloggc:gc-pinot-server.log -javaagent:/opt/pinot/etc/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8008:/opt/pinot/etc/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/configs/pinot.yml"
    volumes:
      - ./server.conf:/server.conf
      - ./data/server_data/segment:/var/pinot/server/data/segment
      - ./data/server_data/index:/var/pinot/server/data/index
```

table config:

```json
{
    "tableName": "<table-name>",
    "tableType": "REALTIME",
    "segmentsConfig": {
      "schemaName": "<schema-name>",
      "retentionTimeUnit": "DAYS",
      "retentionTimeValue": "60",
      "replication": "3",
      "timeColumnName": "date",
      "allowNullTimeValue": false,
      "replicasPerPartition": "3",
      "segmentPushType": "APPEND",
      "completionConfig": {
        "completionMode": "DOWNLOAD"
      }
    },
    "tenants": {
      "broker": "DefaultTenant",
      "server": "DefaultTenant",
      "tagOverrideConfig": {
        "realtimeCompleted": "DefaultTenant_OFFLINE"
      }
    },
    "tableIndexConfig": {
      "noDictionaryColumns": [
        <some-fileds>
      ],
      "rangeIndexColumns": [
        <some-fileds>
      ],
      "rangeIndexVersion": 1,
      "autoGeneratedInvertedIndex": false,
      "createInvertedIndexDuringSegmentGeneration": false,
      "sortedColumn": [
        "date",
        "id"
      ],
      "bloomFilterColumns": [],
      "loadMode": "MMAP",
      "onHeapDictionaryColumns": [],
      "varLengthDictionaryColumns": [],
      "enableDefaultStarTree": false,
      "enableDynamicStarTreeCreation": false,
      "aggregateMetrics": false,
      "nullHandlingEnabled": false
    },
    "metadata": {},
    "routing": {
      "instanceSelectorType": "strictReplicaGroup"
    },
    "query": {},
    "fieldConfigList": [],
    "upsertConfig": {
      "mode": "FULL",
      "hashFunction": "NONE"
    },
    "ingestionConfig": {
      "streamIngestionConfig": {
        "streamConfigMaps": [
          {
            "streamType": "kafka",
            "stream.kafka.topic.name": "<topic-name>",
            "stream.kafka.broker.list": "<kafka-brokers-list>",
            "stream.kafka.consumer.type": "lowlevel",
            "stream.kafka.consumer.prop.auto.offset.reset": "smallest",
            "stream.kafka.consumer.factory.class.name": "org.apache.pinot.plugin.stream.kafka20.KafkaConsumerFactory",
            "stream.kafka.decoder.class.name": "org.apache.pinot.plugin.stream.kafka.KafkaJSONMessageDecoder",
            "stream.kafka.decoder.prop.format": "JSON",
            "realtime.segment.flush.threshold.rows": "0",
            "realtime.segment.flush.threshold.time": "1h",
            "realtime.segment.flush.segment.size": "300M"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "isDimTable": false
}
```

**server.conf file:**

```yaml
pinot.server.netty.port=8098
pinot.server.adminapi.port=8097
pinot.server.instance.dataDir=/var/pinot/server/data/index
pinot.server.instance.segmentTarDir=/var/pinot/server/data/segment
pinot.set.instance.id.to.hostname=true
```

After ingesting data from real-time stream (Kafka in our case) the data grows in the *memory* and the containers faced to OOMKilled error:
[image: server components status issue]

We have no clue about what is happening on the server, would someone help us finding the root cause of this problem?

**P.S. 1:** For following the complete process of how the Pinot is deployed you can see [this repository on github](https://github.com/mostafaghadimi/pinot-dockerized-ansible).

**P.S. 2:** It is known that the size of data in Pinot can be calculated using the following formula:

```
Data size = size of data (retention) * retention period * replication factor
```

For example if we have data with retention of 2d (two days), and each day we have approximately 2 gigabytes of data, and the replication factor equals to 3, the data size is about 2 * 2 * 3 = 12 gigabytes

Comment: I would start the Pinot Server process with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, and then use a tool (YourKit, in my case) to determine what is consuming all of the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is described in the question, the problem is with creating the table not the Apache Pinot itself. Apache Pinot keeps the keys for `Upsert` operation on heap. In order to scale the performance, it is required to increase the Kafka partitions.
Based on the documentation, the default upsert mode is equals to None.